# Sorting user input

Tags: php

I attempting what I thought would be a simple exercise, but unless I’m missing a trick, it seems anything but simple.

Im attempting to clean up user input into a form before saving it. The particular problem I have is with hyphenated town names. For example, take **Bourton-on-the-Water**. Assume the user has Caps lock on or puts spaces next to the hyphens of any other screw up that might come to mind. How do I, within reason, turn it into what it’s meant to be?

Comment: where's the code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trim() to remove whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string. You can also use explode() to break strings into parts by a specified character and then recreate your string as you like.

Comment: You've given me some good ideas which I'll certainly try to develop. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you can really accomplish this is by improving the way the user inputs their data.

For example use a postcode lookup system that enters an address based on what they type.
Or have a autocomplete from a predefined list of towns (similar to how Facebook shows towns).

To consider every possible permutation of Bourton On The Water / Bourton-On-The-Water etc... is pretty much impossible.

Comment: I'm doing what I can with predefined lists for Counties & Country's but suspect that towns would be going to far. However, a post code look up is a very good idea.

Comment: Postcode lookup is great but RoyalMail do charge for the data which is a pain. We use www.postcodeanywhere.com to provide postcode to address lookups - they have a pretty good API. There are other services out there too, have a look around. If you do want a dump of towns and cities there is a pretty good list here: http://www.sqldumpster.com/databases/geographic/30-uk-towns-cities-postcodes.html